# Rails 3 devise, current_user is not accessible in a Model ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

in my project.rb model, I'm trying to create a scope with a dynamic variable:

```
scope :instanceprojects, lambda { 
    where("projects.instance_id = ?", current_user.instance_id)
}
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<Class:0x102fe3af0>
```

Where in the controller I can access `current_user.instance_id`... Is there a reason the model can't access it and a way to get access? Also, is this the right place to create a scope like the above, or does that belong in the controller?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This doesn't make much sense, as you already pointed. The current_user doesn't belong to model logic at all, it should be handled on the controller level.

But you can still create scope like that, just pass the parameter to it from the controller:

```
scope :instanceprojects, lambda { |user|
    where("projects.instance_id = ?", user.instance_id)
}
```

Now you can call it in the controller:

```
Model.instanceprojects(current_user)
```

Comment: that's awesome. trying it now

Comment: I called the scope 'of' so it would read nicely. `Project.of current_user`

Comment: I'm having a hard time googling to find out why -> didn't work (complains about the pipe symbol).  I thought it meant "lambda" but I guess not... (I'm a relative noob to ruby.)

Comment: @marvin - using `->` the parameters are passed into it differently `->(user){ ... }`

Answer (score 33):

The already accepted answer provides a really correct way to achieve this.

But here's the thread-safe version of `User.current_user` trick.

```
class User
  class << self
    def current_user=(user)
      Thread.current[:current_user] = user
    end

    def current_user
      Thread.current[:current_user]
    end
  end
end

class ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_current_user

  def set_current_user
    User.current_user = current_user
  end
end
```

This works as expected, however it can be considered dirty, because we basically define a global variable here.

Comment: Thanks - I had a specific situation where I really needed this and had no way of passing it in. BTW, this code has a few errors - you should use the User.current_user= method from ApplicationController (otherwise, why have it), and also it's set into :current_user, but the reader reads from :user (Took me way to long to see that!)

Comment: I have tried this and works perfect. However in my development environment there is no multi user situation. I'm stil concerned about the comments in other answers about the thread safe issue. Has anyone else tested this in production environment? Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

Ryan Bates lays out a pretty safe way to implement this kind of strategy [in this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/388-multitenancy-with-scopes)

You can [browse the source code here](https://github.com/railscasts/388-multitenancy-with-scopes)

Here he creates a `current_tenant` method, but you could easily substitute `current_user` instead.

Here are the key bits of code...

```
#application_controller.rb
around_filter :scope_current_tenant

private

def current_tenant
  Tenant.find_by_subdomain! request.subdomain
end
helper_method :current_tenant

def scope_current_tenant
  Tenant.current_id = current_tenant.id
  yield
ensure
  Tenant.current_id = nil
end

#models/tenant.rb

def self.current_id=(id)
  Thread.current[:tenant_id] = id
end

def self.current_id
  Thread.current[:tenant_id]
end
```

Then in the model you can do something like...

```
default_scope { where(tenant_id: Tenant.current_id) }
```

Comment: All Railscast's are now freeeee!

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use scopes. If you have set the appropriate associations in models, following piece of code placed in controller should do the trick:

```
@projects = current_user.instance.projects
```