# Rails routing devise_for / resources CRUD overlap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, crud

I've got devise working for my User class, and I'm trying to add some CRUD methods to the users controller. I've read about routing for this, and so long as `devise_for` comes before `resources` it will take precedences, otherwise you will only be accessing non-existent records via /users/sign_in or whatever. Anyway.

I have my CRUD methods working, and even some resources. Say users have many possesssions. I can view a possessions via /users/1/possessions/1, but when I try to delete it, I don't have access to the Devise current_user method. I could delete by looking up the User with params[:user_id], and then finding it's possessions by params[:id], but that's not really secure if I only want the logged in user to be able to delete his/her own possessions.

How can I use Devise's methods from within my User model's CRUD methods?

Answer (score 0):

[Using "current_user" in models in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140703/using-current-user-in-models-in-ruby-on-rails)

http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/47-fetch-current-user-in-models

Answer (score 0):

A better practise might be to not nest the possessions route under user, instead have it on its own as `/possessions/1` and the in your possessions controller to scope all of your finds by the current_user i.e.:

```
def index
  @possessions = current_user.possessions
end

def edit
  @possession = current_user.possessions.find(params[:id])
  ...
end
```

That way you can be sure that the user will only ever be able to see their own items, and they will receive a 404 if they tried to access someone else's possessions.

[Inherited Resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) makes this really easy to do, so you can code your controllers like this:

```
class ProjectsController < InheritedResources::Base
  protected
    def collection
      @projects ||= end_of_association_chain.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    end
end
```

Comment: That makes sense, except that I'm using Mongoid and want `Possessions` to be publicly viewable, so as `Possession` is `embedded_in` `User`, I can't access it without going through the root document (`User`).
Also, this really had no effect on the problem I was having and now I think there must be another cause within my `possessions_controller` in my destroy method, `current_user` is returning nil. It works in the show method, but not in destroy. Any ideas about that?