# Access Devise's current_user in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

How do I go about accessing Devises 'current_user' object inside of a model? I want to automatically append the current users id to a record when they create something. I know that I can manually set the user_id inside of the controller but I feel it would be easier/cleaner if it was handled by the model.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Essentially, this kind of logic doesn't belong in a Model, so you're best to pass `current_user` in through a function in the model or on creation. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742785/rails-3-devise-current-user-is-not-accessible-in-a-model#3742981) sums it up.

I know, I know, that's not the answer you wanted. Unfortunately, it may be cleaner looking to you, but it adds overhead to your model that you really don't want.

Comment: Here's an up arrow to negate that silly misuse of a down arrow! Cheers

Comment: @Kelly I would like to edit your answer to include the idea of *"passing `current_user` to the model"* explicitly as an alternative, but couldn't really figure out how without feeling like I could be changing your answer too much.

Answer (score 2):

Many popular gems need to access the `current_user` in the model such as [paper_trail](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail).

Their approach starts in the controller which captures the `current_user`.

```rb
class ApplicationController
  before_action :set_paper_trail_whodunnit
end
```

Which triggers:

```rb
def set_paper_trail_whodunnit
  if ::PaperTrail.request.enabled?
    ::PaperTrail.request.whodunnit = user_for_paper_trail
  end
end
```

and

```rb
def user_for_paper_trail
  return unless defined?(current_user)
  current_user.try(:id) || current_user
end
```

After the `current_user.id` is saved from the controller, and an auditing action is triggered such as create.

```rb
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail
end
```

Which eventually triggers the following event.

```rb
module PaperTrail
  module Events    
    class Create < Base
      def data
        data = {
          item: @record,
          event: @record.paper_trail_event || "create",
          whodunnit: PaperTrail.request.whodunnit
        },
        # .. more create code here 
    end
  end
end
```

In summary, an approach would be the following.

1. Save the `current_user` using a `before_action` in a controller
2. Store the `current_user` somewhere that can be accessed later in the model, in `paper_trail`'s case that is `PaperTrail.request.whudunnit`
3. Access your store inside the model

Comment: Thank for trying to answer this good question. When you implement after_save on a model created by the connected user, it is nice to have the current_user.