# Ruby-On-Rails - Can't access current_user in post model/ post controller#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, watermark

I'm relatively new to coding so apologies if this is super simple, but I've been stuck on this problem for about a week now! I'm trying to access an image that's already been uploaded, to be used as a watermark for another image. I've cut out what I think is necessary but if there#s anything you think is missing, please let me know.

I want to access the current_user and use that id to define the path to the url. I know this code works to an extent:

```
User.find(1).watermarkimage.url(:medium)
```

But I want to replace the 1 with the current user.

Under the :watermark_path, I've tried: 
User.find(attachment.instance.user_id).watermarkimage; attachment.instance.user_id.watermarkimage; owner.watermarkimage, current_user; current_user.id, User.find(current_user.id) and quite a few others with no luck. A lot of the time I'm getting:

```
Couldn't find User with 'id'=
```

The user_id comes up in the parameters which is the thing that's really confusing me. If you could let me know why I can't access it in this model I'd really appreciate it.

Post Model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
before_create :owner
belongs_to :user
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :media, presence: true
validates :caption, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 300 }

def owner
 self.user_id = current_user.id
end

has_attached_file :media, :styles => lambda { |attachment| {
              :large => {
                  :processors => [:watermark],
                  :geometry => "800>",
                  :watermark_path => self.current_user.watermarkimage.url(:medium),
                  :position => 'SouthEast'
              }
             }
            }, :default_url => "#{Rails.root}/public/apercha logo.jpg"
validates_attachment_content_type :media, :content_type => /.*/
```

Post Controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController  
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  ...
    def create
@post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)

if @post.save
  flash[:success] = "Your post has been created!"
  redirect_to posts_path
else
  flash[:alert] = "Your new post couldn't be created!  Please check the form."
  render 'new'
end
end
```

Schema

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
...
  t.integer  "user_id"
...
end
  add_index "posts", ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id", using: :btree
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is meant to replace the code in the `has_attached_file` validation,  you should be able to say something like`user.watermarkimage.url(:image)`.

If `post belongs_to :user` you should be able to call that user on a post instance with just `user`. The model shouldn’t have to know about who the current user is ([Access Devise's current_user in Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545116/access-devises-current-user-in-model)).

Also, since you’re creating a post through `current_user.posts.build` in your controller, it will set the user on the post for you. You don’t need the `before_create` call back to set the user.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for answering. I understand the logic now so appreciate that! When I do that though, I get undefined method `watermarkimage' for nil:NilClass under NoMethodError in PostsController#create. Any ideas?

Comment: I goofed. Since it’s in the validation stage, I believe you actually do need to call `self.user.watermarkimage.url(:medium)`