# How to use devise current_user in Active Model Serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, active-model-serializers

I'm using **Active Model Serializer 0.10.7** in rails 5

and I wanna know how to access devise current_user in serializer.

`current_user` is supposed to be set for scope by default.

according to doc

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/serializers.md#controller-authorization-context

but my code doesn't work well...

anybody knows about this?

```
class BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :id, :title, :url, :image, :is_reviewed

  def is_reviewed
    object.reviews.pluck(:user_id).include?(current_user.id)
  end
end
```

and Book controller look like this.

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @books = Book.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {render json: @books, each_serializer: BookSerializer}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I can access current_user in Book controller.

but it gets nil in serializer...

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to pass a scope into your serializer when instantiating it in the controller (or elsewhere for that matter). I appreciate that this is for individual objects and not arrays of objects:

```
BookSerializer.new(book, scope: current_user)
```

Then in your `Book Serializer` you can do:

```
class BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :id, :title, :url, :image, :is_reviewed

  private

  def is_reviewed
    object.reviews.pluck(:user_id).include?(current_user.id)
  end

  def current_user
    scope
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Devise doesn't expose the `current_user` helper to models or serializers - you can pass the value to the model from the controller, or set it in a storage somewhere.

Some examples from other answers:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742981/385532

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5545264/385532

Answer (score 2):

in application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  serialization_scope :view_context


end
```

---

in serializer:

```
class BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :id, :title, :url, :image, :is_reviewed

  def is_reviewed
    user = scope.current_user
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks but don't work... does that work for devise current_user?

Comment: what's your gem version? monsieur

Comment: NoMethodError - undefined method `user_for_serializer' for #<#<Class:0x007fd246e2b7e0>:0x007fd24a06be58>:

Comment: Sorry. I made mistake. this is my gem  version `active_model_serializers (0.10.7)`

Comment: same version i am using... '  o  '

Comment: can you show your api controller code with serializer ?

Comment: I tested now in another app setttings from my answer and it works. `rails 5.1.4` `active_model_serializers (0.10.6)`. I don't sure if it will help, but I initilize my serializer with that settings: `Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer = :json`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using active_model_serializers gem, then it is straight forward.

In your serializer just use the keyword `scope`.

Eg:-

```rb
class EventSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes(
    :id,
    :last_date,
    :total_participant,
    :participated
  )

  def participated
    object.participants.pluck(:user_id).include?(scope.id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass view context into serializer from controller when you want to intialize serializer your self instead of `render json: book`.

```
# controller
BookSerializer.new(book, scope: view_context)

# serializer
class BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :id, :title, :url, :image, :is_reviewed

  private

  def is_reviewed
    object.reviews.pluck(:user_id).include?(scope.current_user.id)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used tried to use the scope solution other's have suggested but found it is not easy to test. An alternative I've found is to just pass the current_user to the serializer.
So your controller would look like;

```rb
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @books = Book.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {render json: @books, each_serializer: BookSerializer, user: current_user}
    end
  end
end
```

and in your serializer you would do;

```rb
class BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :url, :image, :is_reviewed

  def is_reviewed
    object.reviews.pluck(:user_id).include?(instance_options[:user].id)
  end
end
```

You can either define the user everywhere you call this serializer, or do an `&.z` or check it's presence in the serializer so that you don't get errors if it is not defined

Answer (score -1):

seems there is a typo, you have `is_reviewed` and you defined method `has_reviewed`
so it should be like this

```
class BookSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :id, :title, :url, :image, :is_reviewed

  def is_reviewed
    object.reviews.pluck(:user_id).include?(current_user.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: sorry mistake !! but that's not a issue.

Comment: @OtaniShuzo you can pass explicitly like `render json: {books: BookSerializer.new(current_user, root: false)}`