# Pass Account ID to New User During Sign Up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Currenntly, my application is designed using Devise for authentication. I have it so when the first user signs up, an account is created in an Accounts table and the account_id is passed to the User table.  I also have it set so that each time a new account is created that user is tagged as an admin. Finally, I have it working where the admin can create new users.

My problem is that at the time the new users are created I need to have these users be assigned the same account_id as the admin to tie the users together.  I can do this if I add an account_id field on the form and have the admin manually enter it.  What I want to have is that this is automated in the background.

I tried many varieties without success. This is one of the unsuccesful attempts where I put the following in the user.rb

```
before_save :add_account_id_from_parent     

   def add_account_id_from_parent       
    return true unless self.users.present?       
    self.users.update_attribute(:account_id, 1)    
   end
```

I used the number "1" just to see if I could get anything automated and placed in that field.

Like I said manually everything works, but I want it so the acocunt_id is automatically added during sign up based on the admins account_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused why you are calling `self.users`. If I understand correctly, you want to assign `account_id` to `1` after a new user is created (as a test). You can do that like this:

```
before_save :add_account_id_from_parent

def add_account_id_from_parent
  self.account_id = 1
end
```

You don't need to actually update the record since this is assigned *before* save, and save will write the new value to the db.

Again I might be missing something, if so please clarify.

**UPDATE**:

If you're validating that `account` is present, you'll need to change the callback to a `before_validation` instead of `before_save`, like so:

```
before_validation :add_account_id_from_parent
```

Comment: I do not believe you are missing anything, I just was wrong in how I was writing it.  When I try your code -- it says account cannot be blank so it will not save user.  Also, in your above code it adds a fixed number.  What I need it to do is not add 1 but look to the account_id of the admin that is creating the account and input that id into the new users account_id.  Am I correct that I added the above to user.rb

Comment: The problem is that you have a validation checking that `account` is present, and that is failing so it never gets to the save step. Switch `before_save` to `before_validation` and that should work.

Comment: Re: your second question, I don't have enough info to write that code. What is the name of the variable for the current user? Usually that would be `current_user`. Assuming that's the case, you could just replace `1` by `current_user.account_id`, i.e.: `self.account_id = current_user.account_id`.

Comment: That worked like a charm.  Thank you.  Do you happen to have any idea on how I can pull the admin's account_id into the new users account_id field so they will be tied together.

Comment: Did you read my last comment? If you use `current_user` for your logged-in user, then you can assign the account id the way I suggested.

Comment: p.s. would appreciate it if you could mark this as the answer :)

Comment: Sorry for not marking it as answered.  I had to cut off early 1 am -- but will continue working on it tonight and hopefully get it set.

Comment: Cut off at 1am! I wouldn't call that "early"! I'm lucky if I make it until midnight. Anyway thanks! Let me know if I can help with anything else.

Comment: shioyama: O continue to try but with no success to use **self.account_id = current_user.account_id** any variation I try returns this error **undefined local variable or method `current_user'** I know why the error is occurring but do not see how to get around it -- endless searching on the web has not lead me any closer to a solution

Comment: `current_user` will only work if you are using a name with that variable to store the logged-in user. Is that what you are using?

Comment: I figured as much and that is my problem -- I do not think I am using any variable yet to store the logged in user -- so what I have tried -- unsucessfully to do is the following: add this into the application controller:     before_filter do |c|      
    User.current_user = User.find(c.session[:user]) unless c.session[:user].nil?      
    end   
and then add this into the user.rb  cattr_accessor :current_user  but that did not work and truthfully the only reason I took that path is someone else on the web said it worked for them -- but I am not sure why?

Comment: I am using devise for authentication and have run across numerous post that state using 'current_user' with devise cna be tricky --

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742785/rails-3-devise-current-user-is-not-accessible-in-a-model#11670283 I don't know devise though so I'm not sure it will work with it.

Comment: I will have to continue to try other methods -- I tried your reference but still get **undefined local variable or method `current_user'** -- if unsuccesful maybe I will post this speciifc question to see if any devise people may have the answer -- thanks again ---

Comment: What if you switch `self.account_id = current_user.account_id` to `self.acount_id = User.current_user.account_id`? That should not give you an undefined error if you have defined the method.