# Model: undefined local variable or method `current_user'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

I'm new to Rails, Rails_Admin and Devise. Trying to get current_user, which I thought should be provided by Devise, in a model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :items

  after_initialize do
    if new_record?      
      self.user_id = current_user.id unless self.user_id
    end                                
  end  
end
```

In Rails_Admin I get:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<Item:0x007fc3bd9c4d60>
```

Same with

```
self.user_id = _current_user.id unless self.user_id
```

I saw there's a line in config/initializers/rails_admin.rb but not sure what it does:

```
  config.current_user_method { current_user } # auto-generated
```

Comment: `current_user` is only defined in your controllers/views

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to make it available in models as well? Or is that a security problem?

Comment: models should not be aware of it, that's not their responsibility

Answer (score 6, accepted):

current_user doesn't belong to model. This answer has some explanation.

[Rails 3 devise, current_user is not accessible in a Model ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742785/rails-3-devise-current-user-is-not-accessible-in-a-model#3742981)

Answer (score 4):

You can't refer to current_user in the models because it is only available to *Controllers* and *Views*. This is because it's defined in *ApplicationController*. The way to get around this is to set the *user* attribute on Item when you create it in the controller.

```
class ItemsController < Application Controller

  def create
    @item = Item.new(params[:item])
    @item.user = current_user # You have access to current_user in the controller
    if @item.save
      flash[:success] = "You have successfully saved the Item."
      redirect_to @item
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the Item."
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Additionally to make sure your *Item* isn't saved without the *user* attribute set, you can put a validation on the user_id. If it isn't set, the *Item* won't save to the database.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id
  belongs_to :user,
             :inverse_of => :items # You probably don't need this inverse_of. In this
                                   # case, Rails can infer this automatically.

  validates :user_id,
            :presence => true
end
```

The validation in essence solves what you were trying to do when you were setting user in the model with the after_initialize callback. A guarantee that the *Item* isn't saved without that information.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. I'm using Rails_Admin and wanted to have those attributes set (as opposed to manually select it every time I create a new row) when I enter data (sometimes hundreds of rows) in the admin console. At first glance, it seems that the Rails_Admin controller is not accessible. Maybe there's a way to overwrite it though.

Comment: Rails_Admin's functionality is more-so as a database administration system that's built on top of rails as opposed to interacting directly with the DB. But that functionality is only going to go so far unfortunately and won't be able to handle all application logic that would go in the controller.