# Authorizing non-logged-in user behavior in rails with cancan and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, authorization, cancan

```
Post: hidden: boolean
```

I want the logged in user could see all the posts, and the non-logged-in user only have access to posts whose hidden fields are false.
So I write like this in cancan's Ability Model:

```
if user_signed_in?
    can :read, Post
else 
    can :read, Post, :hidden => false
end
```

but accessing the helper user_signed_in is not allowed in Model.
As stated in this question: [Rails 3 devise, current_user is not accessible in a Model ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742785/rails-3-devise-current-user-is-not-accessible-in-a-model#3742981). While we could using some tricks to access the helper, its not proper to do that

So, how could I authorize the not-logged-in user properly? Or just use "Include" to use this helper ??

Or should I put this in authentication part? but how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is this:

```
def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

  can :read, Post, :hidden => false

  if User.exists?(user)
    can :read, Post
  end
end
```

With devise, the `current_user` helper method returns the current user when logged in but returns nil when not logged in. It is available in the controllers and views. By default, CanCan does all authorization checks against the return of the `current_user` method.

Now whenever the `can?` method is called from a view or a controller, the return of `current_user` will be passed to a new instance of `Ability` as the local variable `user`.

To check if the user was logged in, I choose to use`User.exists?()`. It's a class method for `ActiveRecord::Base` that will check if that `user` object is persisted in the database. Any other way will work just as well though. For instance, this would work just as well or better:

```
if user.encrypted_password
  can :read, Post
end
```

This will check if the default devise password field exists for the `user` instance. If you haven't done anything too crazy, this will only return a value if the user is logged in. If the second option works for your situation, it may be superior because you won't even have to query the database.

Semi-relevant tip, check out a role handling gem like [Rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify). It is great when used in conjunction with CanCan.

Comment: So, I have to delete the line: user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in) in cancan?(This is always written by default)

Comment: Well...I think the former answer may work better?!THE `user ||= User.new`, I feel that this only means that CanCan would handle the user-with-no-role and user-not-logged-in at the same time. For example,  we could put the last line like `else can :read, :all`, so all people could read, no matter whether they are logged in.

Comment: Abilities from any `can` method outside of all conditions, like `can :read, Post, :hidden => false` in my example, will be available to all visitors. `else can :read, :all` isn't as good for this, because it's only for users that didn't meet any other condition, it's not for all users. See the difference? My last comment wasn't well worded, I meant you brought up a good point. `user ||= User.new` is actually quite necessary. From my answer for example, my second method of deciding if a user is logged in would throw a NilClass::NoMethod error for non-logged-in users without out it.