# How do you disallow anonymous user from directly accessing a controller (allow only access from another controller)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How do you allow a user only being able to access a controller action only if he had accessed another controller.

For example, i have a set of Products which will go to NumberController ('new' action) - i prevent the anonymous to go to the new action in the NumberController, directly and only allow the anonymous user coming form the Products page which the anonymous user had selected before that.

One solution that i had read is that you can use session cookies to disallow the user to access the new action in the NumberController and the other is using scoped query for example:

```
Product.find(params[:id]).Number.find(params[:product_id])
```

or something similar and use nested resources. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Authorizing non-logged-in user behavior in rails with cancan and devise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639272/authorizing-non-logged-in-user-behavior-in-rails-with-cancan-and-devise)

Answer (score 1):

This answer posted on this question:

[Authorizing non-logged-in user behavior in rails with cancan and devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639272/authorizing-non-logged-in-user-behavior-in-rails-with-cancan-and-devise)

illustrates how you can handle anonymous (not logged in) users with CanCan authorization. It's fairly straightforward.

Also, importantly, CanCan is currently fairly out of date. **CanCanCan** (https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) is a fairly drop-in replacement for CanCan that's being actively maintained, works with Rails 4, etc. It will handle your anonymous user issue just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try [cancan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan?view=asciicast) and [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify).

you could use them to set a role for a user so will be able to verify if this user have a role (admin) to access this action...

Comment: I would like the anonymous user to do that and not according to roles.