# Users list with follow/unfollow button

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an `Users list`, where I need to put `follow/unfollow` button for each user when I'm signed in.

There will be some other places where I want to use same method to follow topic/group and etc. So I think it would be best to write an association to avoid additional queries every time I need these buttons.

My `user_followings` table structure

```
| id | user_id | recipient_id | 
| 1  | 1       | 2            | 
| 2  | 3       | 2            | 
| 3  | 10      | 3            |
```

So here user with id=1 follows user => 2...

So bassicaly there is `has_many` association type, because user is following many other users. But I came up with an idea to add `has_one` association type, where I will put an additional condition `recipient_id=current_user.id` so only one record will be left and it shows following status.

If I succeed making this `association`, there will be super easy to check following status via `user.following.nil?` in view with no additional queries, caching and etc.

I have made this once before in my CakePHP app, the SQL query looks like:

```
ON (`UserFollowing`.`recipient_id` = `User`.`id` AND `UserFollowing`.`user_id` = 1)
```

But CakePHP lets to bind relations on the fly, so I added current_user.id from the session directly to association conditions.

I can't do this in Rails, because I can't put `current_user.id` in model to describe conditions:

```
user.rb
has_one :following, :class_name => 'UserFollowing', :conditions => {:user_id => current_user.id}
```

Method Nb. 2

Maybe I can solve this using `:through`, but I can't find any example to get results from the same `users` table from which I'm making the association.

Method Nb. 3

Do it using scope [Rails 3 devise, current_user is not accessible in a Model ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742785/rails-3-devise-current-user-is-not-accessible-in-a-model)

Not sure, which way is the best...

Comment: try `:conditions => {:recipient_id => current_user.id}`

Comment: sorry, I was misspelled with current_user.id. I need to give received user.id for the recipient_id. This doesn't work either :conditions => {:recipient_id => user.id}

Comment: I think you want "users.id" but honestly I didn't understand what the question is

Comment: Sorry. More details added!

Comment: Are you trying to implement twitter like functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although it's not a direct answer to your question: consider the gem: [acts_as_follower](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower). I used it for a similar situation and it seems to fit your needs. It's possible to let anything follow anything else - check it out...

Answer (score 0):

Please read Chapter 11 for this question specifically. Read the whole book for A-Z about building a twitter like app.

[Ruby On Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)

Comment: There are better table logic than mine, but still no good way to echo follow/unfollow buttons for each user in users list. Tutorial suggests to use model method to check button status. So there would be +30 queries per users page... :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found the way to do this with scopes:

```
  # user.rb
  scope :with_relations, lambda { |current_user_id|
    has_one :user_following, :foreign_key => 'recipient_id', :conditions => {:user_id => current_user_id}
    where(:status => 1)
  }

  # users_controller.rb
  @users = User.with_relations(current_user.id).limit(30).order('last_action desc')
```