# Follow actions for all instances of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relationship, twitter-follow

Currently I have full functionality when displaying the Follow/unfollow button for one user.
I'm able to follow and unfollow any user properly.

However, When displaying a list of all users and displaying a Follow/Unfollow button on each.

When I click on follow I get.

I get **undefined local variable or method `following' for #<#:0x007fa8a9b4f448>**
on line two of _unfollow.html.erb - *See photo below for full error*

I'm passing in the variable when I render the partial.

```
<%= render 'follow_aud_form', :following => following if signed_in? %>
```

I'm also able to inspect "following" and see the instance data.

After clicking when I go back, it actually follow/unfollows the selected user, however it generates the error first

See code below

users_controller

```
def following
 @title = "Following"
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 @users = @user.followed_users
 render 'show_follow'
end

def followers
  @title = "Followers"
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @users = @user.followers
  render 'show_follow'
end
```

show_follow.html.erb

```
<% @users.each do |following|%>

        <div class="span1">
          <%= render 'follow_aud_form', :following => following if signed_in? %>
        </div>

    <% end %>
```

follow_aud_form

```
<div id="follow_form">
  <% if current_user.following?(following) %>
    <%= render 'unfollow', :following => following %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'follow', :following => following %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
```

_follow_html

```
|__<%= @gaza_id = following.id %>__|
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @gaza_id)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow",:type => :image, :src => "/assets/follow.png" %>
<% end %>
```

_unfollow.html

```
|__<%= @slim_id = following.id %>__|
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(@slim_id),
             html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
  <%#= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-large" %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfollow",:type => :image, :src => "/assets/following.png" %>
<% end %>
```

I've also viewed [Users list with follow/unfollow button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634259/users-list-with-follow-unfollow-button)

[image]

Comment: Please check (and tell us) the line in which the error is raised. It seems that should be somewhere where you are doing some_obj.following (maybe the following? method inside the User class). Please provide the logic inside this method so I can check.

Comment: I often run into issues myself when I don't explicitly use the `template` option in my render calls, it might be worthwhile to specify the full path and use the `locals` block as well. For example,  try changing `<%= render 'follow_aud_form', :following => following if signed_in? %>` to `<%= render :template => 'some_controller/follow_aud_form', :locals => {:following => following} if signed_in? %>`

Comment: @RafaelMartinez Add line number and photo

Comment: @Noz Same thing, when I try <%= render :template => 'users/_follow_aud_form', :locals => {:following => following} if signed_in? %> and also without :locals

Answer (score 0):

Just try changing the _show_follow.html.erb to:

```
<% @users.each do |following|%>

    <div class="span1">
      <% f = signed_in? ? following : ''
      <%= render 'follow_aud_form', :following => f %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

I believe the only problem you have is that the local var `:following` is not created unless you the user is signed in. The change proposed just makes sure that the local variable is created anyway.

Comment: If you don't want to show the "follow_aud_form" unless the user is logged in you should use parentesis: <%= render('follow_aud_form', :following => following) if signed_in? %>