# Rails 3: Get current user_id to save in different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a user and a article model.
When I save an article I also need to save which user created the article therefore I need his ID. So I need to know which user created it?

My article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :title, :description, :user_id

  validates_length_of :title, :minimum => 5
end
```

My articles_controller.rb

```
def create
    @article = Article.new(params[:article])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @article, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

My Article _form

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
```

So how to i set the user_id in the article model correctly? I would like the one who has a session! I have a helper_method in the application_controller But i am not sure how to use it.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  helper_method :current_user

  private
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: check out this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742785/rails-3-devise-current-user-is-not-accessible-in-a-model#3742981

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do something like this in your controller:

```
def create
  @article = current_user.articles.build(params[:article])
  ...
end
```

OR

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(params[:article].merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
  ...
end
```

But i would prefer the first one.

Comment: I submitted an answer a few minutes ago that was different, but i like @jokklan's first option as well.  That will take advantage of the relationship between users and articles to create a new article with it's user_id attribute automatically set to the currently logged in user.

Comment: Is build a method in the article model?

Comment: build is a auto-generated method, for more information, take a look here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: build works on relations. current_user.articles.build is like Article.new but where the relation is created so the new article belongs to the user (`user_id` is set to current_user.id). See more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-collection-build.