# rails 4 associated models with class_name in select, shows all. Some advise needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

As I am learning RoR now, I would like to know a more appropriated (rails) way to achieve that the application only shows associated resources.

Right now I have the following models:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :billing_accounts
    has_many :addresses
end 

class BillingAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :invoice_address, 
               class_name: "Address", 
               foreign_key:"invoice_address_id"
end 

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :billing_accounts
    belongs_to :account
end
```

In my edit.billing_account I have this form:

```
= simple_form_for([:account, @billing_account]) do |f|
    = f.association :invoice_address
```

I expected that only the associated address will be shwon, but this shows "all" address records in the database (also from other user accounts).

Users only should be able to see `account.addresses` and for now I do this with:

```
= f.association :invoice_address, collection: current_user.account.addresses.all
```

But I am sure there is better way to do this inside the models. For every form I now use `current_user.account.MODEL.all` but that is not very DRY I think.

So basically what I want is only to use `=f.association :invoice_address` and BillingAccount should know it only can show the account.addresses.

Suggestions are welcome.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should use `f.simple_fields_for` instead of `f.association` as described here: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models

```
class BillingAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice_address, 
           class_name: "Address", 
           foreign_key:"invoice_address_id"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :invoice_address
end
```

View:

```
= simple_form_for([:account, @billing_account]) do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :invoice_address do |f_address|
    = f_address.input :street
    = f_address.input :zipcode
    ...
```

Don't forget to build invoice_address of account in a controller if it is needed. For example:

```
class BillingAccountController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @billing_account = BillingAccount.new
    @billing_account.build_invoice_address
  end
```

Comment: Hi Chumakoff. Thanks for the suggestion, but I dont want to edit the address_data. With the simple_fields I create a form to edit the address. But I want to associate an account.address to the billing_account.

Comment: I understood you. See my another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set `default_scope` for nested models:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { where(account_id: current_user.account_id) }
```

But in this case you should [define current_user in models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742785/rails-3-devise-current-user-is-not-accessible-in-a-model#11670283)

Comment: HI yukke. I tried this but somehow I keep getting the "undefined local variable or method `current_user" error. But that would be another thing I have to investigate. It does gives me an idea where to look now.

Comment: @Jerry, Take a closer look at my anwer. There's link to current_user hook.

Comment: I did. But also when I follow those solutions I still get the current_user error. As I om rails 4 it seems that somethings are not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using [`has_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) you can use the plural version of the model name rather than `current_user.account.MODEL.all`.

Like this:

```
current_user.account.addresses
```

or

```
current_user.account.billing_accounts
```

It even works the other way with `belongs_to`:

```
@address = Address.last
@address.accounts
```

Comment: Hi Ecnalyr. current_user.account.addresses is working, but I want to get rid of the **current_user.account.MODEL** thing. There has to be a better way to show only account related items.

Comment: I am sure it will be possible just to use = f.association :invoice_address and through the model the application will know it can only use the account.addresses. But I just didn't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add conditions to belongs_to association:

```
class BillingAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :invoice_address, 
               ->(billing_account) { where "account_id = #{billing_account.account_id}" },
               class_name: "Address", 
               foreign_key:"invoice_address_id"
end
```