# Conditional Statements In Ruby on Rails Model File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-models

Is it possible for us to write conditional statements in our Rails model file for example in my case if I want to implement some validations based on if a user is singned_in or not in my Customer.rb file.

```
if user_signed_in?  // if signed_in is true
     //my validation code here
```

then some special validations and

```
else !user_signed_in? // if signed_in is false
     //my validation code here
```

Comment: Hey i think you can try `if` and `elsif`

Answer (score 3):

`current_user`, `user_signed_in?` etc are not available in the model.

[Rails 3 devise, current_user is not accessible in a Model ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742785/rails-3-devise-current-user-is-not-accessible-in-a-model#3742981)

In short, your user-centric conditions should be in the *controller*, the model is to pull & manipulate data *only*...

[image]

I post this image all the time; it shows how a standard *MVC* framework looks. Rails *is* an MVC framework... shows you how the model and other elements work together to get it working properly.

As you can see, the *controller* acts like the "hub" which glues it all together. In order to keep your application structured properly, you'll ideally want to put your mid-level logic in your controller, data-level logic into your model, and superficial logic into your view.

EG:

```
#Model
class Products
   belongs_to :user
end

#controller
def index
   @products = user_signed_in? ? current_user.products : Product.all
end

#view
<% @products.each do |product| %>
   <%= product.name if product.name %>
<% end %>
```

The answer you need is to specify the validation logic you require, allowing you to apply the required data in the controller/model

---

If you wanted to use user validation in the model, you'd have to use conditions at the controller level and pass the results to the model:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @user = User.new user_params
      @user.online = user_signed_in?
   end

   private

   def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:x, :y, :z)
   end
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :online, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Also it's sometimes useful to create "command" or "service" classes to keep this kind of logic away from both controllers _and_ models. https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services

Comment: @RichPeck : My problem is to validate the email id a customer enters, if user_signed_in? is true, then the email must validate with all possible validations. If not signed_in then no need to check for uniqueness , how to solve this, can you please help me ?

Comment: Why don't you just validate the email form; I don't see their being signed in has anything significant to do with it?

Comment: @RichPeck : I am validating the email form but two context is there, if user is logged in then I have to check for all validation includes uniqueness in email id with existing database entries, but if not logged in I don't want to do the validation then. How ?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference. If you're adding an email, why not just validate regardless of whether they're logged in or not?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

`validates :my_attribute, presence: :true, if: :user_signed_in?
validates :my_attribute, presence: :false, unless: :user_signed_in?`